# Spring bean singleton duplication on low performance computers

Tags: java, spring, javafx

So I have this really weird and unsettling problem. On our low performance computers some of our singleton beans are duplicated during the Spring Context initialization. This only occurs on computers with low performing hardware and it happens consistently.

What I can tell so far is that it seems to be happening to a bunch of classes that are in a circular dependency and I suspect it may have something to do with the bean init method. The circular dependency is solved by injecting the LockScreen into the MainContentPane through the init method instead of the constructor.

I have two logs, one from a normal performance computer and one from a low performance computer. The logs shows the difference and the issue. The numbers at the end of the lines are the instance id from the method System.identityHashCode(object). The log format is:

```
LOGLEVEL  [Thread ID]  LoggingClass  Message
```

On a normal performance computer the following printout occurs.

```
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  MainContentPane      Constructor: 869589588
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  MainContentPane      Getting LockScreen In Spring Init....

INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  SessionHandler       Constructor: 939274676
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  SessionHandler       Injected MainContentPane Instance: 869589588
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  UserStateBinder      Constructor: 2010765576
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  UserStateBinder      Injected SessionHandler Instance: 939274676
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  LockScreenLockedController Constructor: 1866179042
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  LockScreenLockedController Injected UserStateBinder Instance: 2010765576
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  LockScreen           Constructor: 204176749
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  LockScreen           Injected LockScreenLockedController Instance: 1866179042
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  LockScreen           This instance: 204176749
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  LockScreen           Bean Factory instance: 1371189401
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  MainContentPane      Injected LockScreen Instance: 204176749
```

Here there are no duplicates.

But if we look at the log from a low performance computer we can see that there are duplicates created after the initialization similar to the one above.

```
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  MainContentPane      Constructor: 22324067
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  MainContentPane      Getting LockScreen In Spring Init....

INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  SessionHandler       Constructor: 32463502
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  SessionHandler       Injected MainContentPane Instance: 22324067
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  UserStateBinder      Constructor: 19793387
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  UserStateBinder      Injected SessionHandler Instance: 32463502
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  LockScreenLockedController Constructor: 29065840
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  LockScreenLockedController Injected UserStateBinder Instance: 19793387
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  LockScreen           Constructor: 12729388
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  LockScreen           Injected LockScreenLockedController Instance: 29065840
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  LockScreen           This instance: 12729388
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  LockScreen           Bean Factory instance: 30716643
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  MainContentPane      Injected LockScreen Instance: 12729388

INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  SessionHandler       Constructor: 11043228
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  SessionHandler       Injected MainContentPane Instance: 22324067
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  UserStateBinder      Constructor: 24902967
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  UserStateBinder      Injected SessionHandler Instance: 32463502
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  LockScreenLockedController Constructor: 17521714
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  LockScreenLockedController Injected UserStateBinder Instance: 19793387
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  LockScreen           Constructor: 16791356
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  LockScreen           Injected LockScreenLockedController Instance: 29065840
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  LockScreen           This instance: 16791356
INFO  [JavaFX Application Thread]  LockScreen           Bean Factory instance: 30716643
```

Here we can see that there is a second set of instances created of all the classes except for the MainContentPane class. The new set of classes are dependency injected with the previous set of instances (check the id's) and the bean factory is the same instance as before.

All these messages are printed on the main thread (JavaFX Application Thread) so there doesn't seem to be a concurrency problem either.

The project also includes an embedded Jetty http server. I don't know if there is anything in Jetty that could cause this issue on a low performance computer.

Versions:

```
JRE(incl. JavaFX): 1.8.0.101
Spring: 4.3.3.RELEASE
Jetty + Websocket: 9.3.6.v20151106
```

I suspected that this problem may have been solved by setting the Spring context setting setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(false). But that didn't help either.

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(false);
        context.register(ClientContext.class,
                MainContext.class,
                CommonContext.class,
                CciContext.class,
                PersistenceContext.class,
                SimulatorContext.class);
        context.refresh();
```

Please tell me if there is any additional information that you need and thank you for any time you put into helping me.

**Edit:**

I have now confirmed that all initilization and all bean access are happening from a single thread. 
I was only able to find two interesting facts in the trace log. 
First, it seems that all initilization happens in the same order even though it is the exact same software version (is Spring initializing in paralell?). 
Second, the medium performance computers does have duplication! They only have duplication (or maybe it's re-initilization?) on the UserStateBinder class. The high performance development computer does not have this issue at all.

We will probably remove spring from our project starting tomorrow as we have been unable to find a solution for this issue. I will still have the current version of the project available to me if anyone else would like me to test any theory.

Comment: So, the circular bean reference happens when it sets your `LockScreen` in the `MainContentPane` ? Is it the same JVM versions on each computers ?

Comment: The circular references are:
LockScreen -> LockScreenLockedController -> UserStateBinder -> SessionHandler -> MainContentPane -> LockScreen and it is solved by letting MainContentPane get the LockScreen bean in it's Spring init method instead of it's constructor. Regarding the JVM, yes it is the same on all computers. The JRE is bundled with the application to ensure it.

Comment: That's sounds really obscure. Can you try a debbugger (with eclipse if possible) on your slow slow computers ?

Comment: Blaming this issue on a "slow" computer I think is a really unlikely root cause. But luckily we do not need to guess: could you please increase your loglevel to TRACE (make sure that `org.springframework` package is included), and upload the two logfiles on pastbin or something? (they are going te be long)

Comment: @Asoub I have thrown a stacktrace in the constructor of the LockScreen object and found that both instantiations occur from creating the context. I will see on monday if there is any possibility to debug the code on one of the low performance computers.

Comment: @GergelyBacso I agree that it does seem really unlikely but right now it is the only common denominator that we seem to find for this issue. This software is proprietary and I don't think my employer would like me to share the entire trace log. Do you have a suggestion as to what I am looking for? I can probably share a specific part of the trace log.

Comment: I expect that reading the two logs in parallel anybody could spot the problem. They will be in sync for some time, then one of them will start reinitializing beans. Whatever happens just before that, that is your clue. If you cannot share the logs, just do this analysis yourself.

Comment: @GergelyBacso Thanks I will try that. I read the debug log but that did not give me anything useful. I will post on monday if I have found anything.

Comment: All right, good luck.

Comment: @GergelyBacso See the edit. I was unable to find the root cause using the TRACE log. Found some other stuff though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of further testing I was able to solve the problem but not find the root cause of the strange behavior.

I suspect that the behavior is somehow caused by Spring initializing beans with some kind of time dependency that changes the behavior. I can't say for sure if this is a result of parallelism or not.

The problem was only occurring in the circular dependency LockScreen -> LockScreenLockedController -> UserStateBinder -> SessionHandler -> MainContentPane -> LockScreen. The circular dependency were broken by moving the constructor dependency in MainContentPane to a Spring init method. The code looked something like this.

```
@Bean(initMethod = "init")
public MainContentPane mainContentPane() {...}

@Bean
public LockScreen lockScreen() {...}

@Bean
public LockScreenLockedController lockScreenLockedController() {...}

@Bean
public UserStateBinder userStateBinder() {...}

@Bean
public SessionHandler sessionHandler() {...}
```

The solution were to explicitly declare dependencies in Spring with the @DependsOn annotation like this.

```
@Bean(initMethod = "init")
public MainContentPane mainContentPane() {...}

@Bean
@DependsOn("lockScreenLockedController")
public LockScreen lockScreen() {...}

@Bean
@DependsOn("userStateBinder")
public LockScreenLockedController lockScreenLockedController() {...}

@Bean
@DependsOn("sessionHandler")
public UserStateBinder userStateBinder() {...}

@Bean
@DependsOn("mainContentPane")
public SessionHandler sessionHandler() {...}
```

I hope this helps anyone that has the same problem and I would still really like to know why Spring behaves this way depending on the performance of the computer.